# The name 'AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper' does not exist in the current context

Tags: android, xamarin.android, azure-active-directory, visual-studio-2019, xamarin-studio

[image]
Hi,I tired to develop Azure Active Directory, But I am facing some issue, I installed Microsoft.Identity.Client NuGet package, but it shows like**"The name 'AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper' does not exist in the current context**" AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationAgentContinuationEventArgs(); Please Help me to find the Solution.

Comment: MSAL v3.x references MonoAndroid 9 as a target framework. You will need to change the target framework in the `Android.csproj` file to 9.0 at least
`<TargetFrameworkVersion>v9.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>`
Then, you should be able to reference `AuthenticationContinuationHelper` .

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XzQWBBP Already my TargetFrameworkVersion is Android 9.0,And My Manifest is https://imgur.com/a/GLq0jgP , But still same Issue!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to find AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper class in [Microsoft.Identity.Client github repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet).

By checking the [Configuration requirements and troubleshooting tips for Xamarin Android with MSAL.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-xamarin-android-considerations#ensure-that-control-returns-to-msal), which should be the latest, it's using

> AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs()

You're probably referring an old doc, please check the latest document and update your code accordingly.